# Do we need to create a new `plasTeX` tag?

Tags: discussion

Indeed, there are questions about this software.
[44 questions about plasTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=plasTeX)

It is available here : [plasTeX is a Python package to convert LaTeX markup to DOM](http://plastex.github.io/plastex/)

Shouldn't we create a tag for plasTeX?

Comment: It's a good idea to add this tag I think. However, not all 44 search results should get this tag, several of them (especially further down the search result) are not really about plasTeX but just mention it briefly, or plasTeX is discussed in the answers but not in the question (and tags should be based on the question only).

Comment: you don't need to create a tag as such you can tag questions anyway, but 44 is more or less the same as 0 given the total question count

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of the 59 pages with 36 tags per page, there are 23 pages with a tag with less than 44 questions: [tags page 26](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags?page=26&tab=popular) That is more than 1500 tags with less than 44 questions.
And there are at least 3 pages of tags with no questions. Maybe we should consider cleaning this up?

Comment: @AndréC The tags with no questions are synonyms of others tags. Tags who don't have a ceratin number of questions are after same time automatically cleaned up by the system - no need to clean them up manually.